# Why does the compiler not recognize my async method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm uncertain why I'm getting the following compiler error. I'm using Microsoft Visual C# 2013 with .NET 4.5.

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<System.Data.DataSet>'.

As I'm reading in a file and iterating through the read lines I'm attempting to kick off some CPU intensive tasks to run asynchronously that I'll wait for after reading in the entire file.  I'm attempting to use example provided under the 'Throttling' heading at [Consuming the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173(v=vs.110).aspx)

This is my async method.

```
protected async Task<ImagePropertyUpdater> processImageAsync(ImagePropertyQueueArgs arg)
{
    ImagePropertyUpdater updater = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        ImageProperties props = new ImageProperties(arg.File, arg.Record.Offset, arg.ImageValidationOptions);
        return new ImagePropertyUpdater(arg, props);
    });

    return updater;
}
```

This is a method called after reading in each line from a text file to queue up the tasks and initiate them.

```
protected Queue<ImagePropertyQueueArgs> ImagePropertiesQueue = new Queue<ImagePropertyQueueArgs>();
protected List<Task<ImagePropertyUpdater>> ImagePropertiesTasks = new List<Task<ImagePropertyUpdater>>();
protected int ActiveTasks = 0;

protected void QueueImagePropertiesTask(
    FileInfo file, ImageBaseRecord record, List<object> valuesList, bool addPageCount,
    ImageValidationOptions imageValidationOptions, String parsedLine, int lineNumber,
    String imageKey, DataSet data)
{
    ImagePropertiesQueue.Enqueue(
        new ImagePropertyQueueArgs(
            file, record, addPageCount, imageValidationOptions,
            parsedLine, lineNumber, imageKey, data));

    if (ActiveTasks <= 10 && ImagePropertiesQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        ImagePropertyQueueArgs args = ImagePropertiesQueue.Dequeue();
        Task<ImagePropertyUpdater> task = processImageAsync(args);
        ImagePropertiesTasks.Add(task);
        ActiveTasks++;
    }
}
```

This is where I'm waiting for the tasks to complete and where I'm getting the error.  The error is on "await Task.WhenAny(ImagePropertiesTasks)" and on "await task".

```
while (ImagePropertiesTasks.Count > 0)
{                    
    Task<ImagePropertyUpdater> task = await Task.WhenAny(ImagePropertiesTasks);                    
    ImagePropertiesTasks.Remove(task);
    ImagePropertyUpdater updater = await task;
    updater.UpdateImageRecord();

    if (ImagePropertiesQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        ImagePropertyQueueArgs args = ImagePropertiesQueue.Dequeue();
        ImagePropertiesTasks.Add(processImageAsync(args));
        ActiveTasks++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget the `async` keyword in the function header of the function where you are getting the error?

Comment: The code snippet throwing the error that you posted doesn't include the portion of the method that would be causing that error.  Please post the entire method.

Comment: @JeffGillispie: Read the error message again. The method *containing* the `await` must be marked `async` (not the method you're *calling*).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Nitram, the async keyword was part of what I missing. I ended up moving the while loop I was using to wait for the tasks to complete out to it's own method.

```
private async void waitForTasks()
{
    while (ImagePropertiesTasks.Count > 0)
    {
        Task<ImagePropertyUpdater> task = await Task.WhenAny(ImagePropertiesTasks);
        ImagePropertiesTasks.Remove(task);
        ImagePropertyUpdater updater = await task;
        updater.UpdateImageRecord();

        if (ImagePropertiesQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            ImagePropertyQueueArgs args = ImagePropertiesQueue.Dequeue();
            ImagePropertiesTasks.Add(processImageAsync(args));
            ActiveTasks++;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I also added the part below to where I was originally waiting for the tasks to complete.

```
Task task = new Task(waitForTasks);
task.Start();
task.Wait();
```